# Symbol's value as variable is void: org-publish-attachment

Tags: org-mode, emacs24

I am getting the below error on executing the block.

```
edebug-eval: Symbol's value as variable is void: org-publish-attachment
```

The code I am executing is below

```
(require 'ox-publish)
(setq org-publish-project-alist
  '(
    ("org-notes"
     :base-directory "~/org/"
     :base-extension "org"
     :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
     :recursive t
     :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
     :headline-levels 4             ; Just the default for this project.
     :auto-preamble t
     )

    ("org-static"
     :base-directory "~/org/"
     :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf"
     :publishing-directory "~/public_html/"
     :recursive t
     :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
     )

    ("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))

    ))
```

More info on error

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable org-publish-attachment)
eval(org-publish-attachment nil)
eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
eval-last-sexp(nil)
call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
```

I am using Emacs 24.3.1 on Ubuntu.

When I enter the below command I cannot find org-publish-attachment too.

```
M-x org-publish-
```

Comment: What org version are you using? Do `C-h v org-version`. Also `M-x org-publish-attachment` will not work because it is not an interactive function [[ref](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3555/115)]. Also check out [emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com) for more QnA related to emacs in general, including org-mode. Your snippet works fine for me on emacs 25.0 and org-mode 8.2.10 (latest from Melpa).

Comment: Fixed. I did this http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#installing-via-elpa

Answer (score 1):

I was using the org mode that came with Emacs. I again installed org from http://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#installing-via-elpa

I had to install twice as first time compilation failed. But now everything works fine. Thanks guys.